# Post to group wall using Facebook SDK .net 2015

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

It seems that nowdays there's no way to allow to post onto facebook user groups via a new, unreviewed app.

I've created an App with live features availible to gen public, with approvements for email, public_profile, user_friends.

I'm trying to post on the wall of a group I've created and I'm an admin of.

Now, when firing up my code, I get the nasty "OAuthException - #200) (#200) Insufficient permission to post to target..." exception.

Posting my wall work perfectly...

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

   private const  long GroupId = 15473890820xxxx;
    //
    // GET: /Home/
    public ActionResult Index(string code)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to Facebook App Demo!";

        //user denied permissions on Facebook. 
        if (Request["error_reason"] == "user_denied")
        {
            //this is not implemented. For reference only.
            return RedirectToAction("LogOn", "Account");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
        {
            ViewBag.Error = "There was an error while loggin into Facebook. Please try again later.";
            return RedirectToAction("LogOn", "Account");
        }

        var fb = new FacebookClient();
        dynamic result = fb.Post("oauth/access_token", new
        {

            client_id = "93199615018xxxx",                
            client_secret = "2089ae4447877e7388500b844235xxxx",               
            redirect_uri = "http://localhost:13301/",
            code = code
        });

        var appToken = result.access_token as string;

        // update the facebook client with the access token so 
        // we can make requests on behalf of the user
        fb.AccessToken = appToken;

        //get extended App/User Token
        dynamic result2  = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new
        {

            client_id = "93199615018xxxx"

            client_secret = "2089ae4447877e7388500b844235xxxx",

            grant_type="fb_exchange_token",
            fb_exchange_token = appToken,
           // code = code
        });

        var extendedAppToken = result2.access_token as string;
        //generate Extended User Token (valid for 60 days)

        Session["Facebooktoken"] = extendedAppToken; 

        dynamic me = fb.Get("me/accounts");

        var response = fb.Get("/me/accounts?access_token=" + extendedAppToken) as JsonObject;

        return View(me);

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection collection) //rename to PostWall
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to Facebook App Demo!";

        // Post to the wall..
        try
        {
            if (Session["Facebooktoken"] != null)
            {
                string message = collection["txtPost"].ToString();
                FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(Session["Facebooktoken"].ToString());

                dynamic result = client.Post(GroupId+"/feed", new
                {
                    message = message
                });

                ViewBag.SaveMessage = "Successfuly Post on your wall : " + result.id;
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("LogOn", "Account");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
        }

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Account/

    public ActionResult LogOn()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {

        var facebookAppId = "93199615018xxxx";

        var facebookAppSecret = "2089ae4447877e7388500b844235xxxx";

        var facebookRedirectUrl = "http://localhost:13301/";
        //
        var facebookScope = "email,publish_pages,publish_actions,manage_pages,user_managed_groups,user_hometown,user_website";

        if (facebookAppId != null && facebookAppSecret != null && facebookRedirectUrl != null && facebookScope != null)
        {
            var url = string.Format(@"https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}", facebookAppId, facebookRedirectUrl, facebookScope);

            Response.Redirect(url, true);
        }

        return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

}
```

Any clue on how to set up an testing environment for above functionality without the extra-round of establishing a fully fledged App that has to be reviewed by Facebook admins? I've looked on testing versions for Apps and Users, but no groups either.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: What permissions does your access token have? The permission required to post to your feed and to a groups feed are different. As per the documentation to post to a group you need user_managed_groups and publish_actions - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/group/feed#publish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Darren, thanks for your considerations. It seems like due to my privacy restrictions I couldnt get any group info of my personal account. Either programmatically, nor manually in Facebooks Graph API Explorer.

It worked finally on an business (fan)'Page' profile by getting an 'long-lived' Page Access Token in facebooks [Access Token Debuger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token/).

Yes, user_managed_groups and publish_actions had been enabled.